# Hard limit question

Tags: limits

I can't compute limit :  $$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(\cfrac {\tan x}{x}\right)^{\cfrac{1}{x^3}}.$$ I do "de l'Hospital rule" two times and i get worse limit with the same result "$\cfrac{0}{0}$". Wolfram is saying that this limit is "$ + \infty $ ". Can someone explain me, or give solution step by step? Maybe there is a quicker way.

Comment: What do you mean by tgx?

Comment: Perhaps try first using a $\ln$ to bring down the exponent?

Comment: tanx * that is it

Comment: i have tried it to do de l'hospital rule

Comment: Ok, to notate that in mathjax, use '/tan x' replacing the 's with dollar signs. Same thing for lim to appear nicer, '/lim'. These gives $\tan x$ and $\lim$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It is a $1^\infty$ indetermination form, therefore you can reduce it to something with exponential and logarithm.

Since everithing is positive, your function equals $e^{\frac{1}{x^3}\ \log(\frac{\tan x}{x})}$ and you have:

$$\frac{\tan x}{x} = 1 + \frac{1}{3} x^2 + \text{o}(x^2)$$

by Taylor expansion, therefore:

$$\left( \frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^3}} = e^{\frac{1}{x^3}\ \log (1 + \frac{1}{3} x^2 + \text{o}(x^2))} = e^{\frac{1}{x^3}\ ( \frac{1}{3} x^2 + \text{o}(x^2))} \approx e^{\frac{1}{3x}}$$

by usual $\log$ aproximation.

Now your limit can be easily computed.

Comment: ye, but i have to do it only with using de l'hospital rule, i can use "the limits" like tanx/x=1 when x goes to 0 no approximation

Comment: Then use L'Hopital's Rule after taking logarithms.  You may need to do it two or three times, but you'll get where you need to be.

Comment: *"but i have to do it only with using de l'hospital rule"* LOL, typical textbook useless question, I guess... In real life you usually don't run with an arm bound behind your back; then why must you solve a question on limits using only one technique, the worst one to do the job?

Comment: no, im the first year student, thats why, we have got only introduction to taylor series

Comment: *First year* of... What? College? I don't want to argue, I'm just curious: where I'm from, Taylor approximation is a first year course topic.

Comment: btw can i know why u wrote only 2 polynomials of taylor expansion ? Does it make a difference ? And second question is how did u get rid of log  in last equation ?

Comment: I got rid of $\log$ by using the standard first order approximation $\log(1 + y) = y + \text{o}(y)$ with $y=\frac{1}{3}x^2 + \text{o}(x^2)$ (which tends to $0$ as $x\to 0^+$). And I took only the first two terms of the Taylor expansion of $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ because they suffice, i.e. they are enough to do the computations; all the other terms are hidden into the remainder term $\text{o}(x^2)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems strange to me because *Taylor's theorem* is a topic usually covered in the first year-first semester course in Analysis for engineers of all types (aviation, mechanics, etc...)  where I'm from. ;-)

Comment: yea, we used it(taylor expansion) to prove some inequalities, and other things, we normally will get: series (and especially taylor series)  during calculus 3 which is at 3 semester.

Comment: Oh, 3rd semeter, I see. OK, paweta, thanks a lot for letting me know: you really satisfied my curiosity. Btw, you should keep in mind Robert Shore's tips, which are really helpful in solving your problem. ;-)